# QListView & QIdentityProxyModel

Tags: qlistview, pyside6, python-3.10, qabstractlistmodel, qidentityproxymodel

I have a test code for `QListView` & `QIdentityProxyModel`.

When I implement `QIdentityProxyModel`, the error occured at the `setData` , func of `dataChanged`.If I don't implement it, the error didn't occur.

I tried to do the same thing by `PyQt6`, but the result was the same.

I tried to do by command prompt, no error massage.

On the contrary, I can success implementing `QIdentityProxyModel` on the case of `QTreeView`, `QTableView` with no problem.I have been thinking `QListView` is the easiest in these viewer.

Where is the problem in my code?

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class ListView(QtWidgets.QListView):

    def __init__(self,  parent=None):
        super(ListView, self).__init__(parent)  
         
    def insertItem(self):
         self.model().insertRows(0, 1)
         self.model().setData(self.model().index(0, 0), ListItem(text="Hallo!"))   
                
class ListItem(object):

    def __init__(self, text="", parent=None):
        super(ListItem, self).__init__()
        self.data = []
        self.text = "Hi!" if not text else text      
 
class ListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListModel, self).__init__(parent)           
        self.items = []

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)

    def headerData(self, index):
        return "LIST"

    def index(self, row, column, _parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):    
        if row >= len(self.items) - 1:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        if self.items:            
            childIndex = self.createIndex(row, column, self.items[row])      
            return childIndex
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if 0 <= row < self.rowCount() and 0 <= column < self.columnCount():        
                return self.items[row].text
        
    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            if 0 <= row < self.rowCount():               
                self.items[row] = value
                self.dataChanged["QModelIndex", "QModelIndex"].emit(index, index)               
                return True                          
        return False

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if row > len(self.items) - 1:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        elif self.items:            
            childIndex = self.createIndex(row, column, self.items[row])      
            return childIndex
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def insertRows(self, position, rows=1, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, position, position+rows-1)
        for i in range(rows):
            self.items.insert(position+i, ListItem())
        self.endInsertRows()
        self.dataChanged["QModelIndex", "QModelIndex"].emit(parent, parent)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
        self.endResetModel()
        return True

class ListIdentityModel(QtCore.QIdentityProxyModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListIdentityModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def mapFromSource(self, sourceIndex):
        if not sourceIndex.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()        
        return self.createIndex(sourceIndex.row(), sourceIndex.column(), sourceIndex.internalPointer())  

    def mapSelectionFromSource(self, selection):
        sourceIndexes = selection.indexes()
        proxySelection = QtCore.QItemSelection(sourceIndexes[0], sourceIndexes[-1])
        return proxySelection        

    def mapSelectionToSource(self, selection):
        proxyIndexes = selection.indexes()
        sourceSelection = QtCore.QItemSelection(proxyIndexes[0], proxyIndexes[-1])
        return sourceSelection    

    def mapToSource(self, proxyIndex):
        if not proxyIndex.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        return self.sourceModel().createIndex(proxyIndex.row(), proxyIndex.column(), proxyIndex.internalPointer())

    def setSourceModel(self, sourceModel):
        self.beginResetModel()
        super(ListIdentityModel, self).setSourceModel(sourceModel)    
        self.endResetModel()

    
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([]) if QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() is None else QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()

    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    pushbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("insert item")
    
    main_view = ListView()        
    model = ListModel(main_view)
    main_view.setModel(model)
    #comment or uncomment
    identity_view = ListView()
    identityModel = ListIdentityModel()
    identity_view.setModel(identityModel)
    identityModel.setSourceModel(model)
    #

    hboxlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()    
    hboxlayout.addWidget(pushbutton)
    hboxlayout.addWidget(main_view)
    #
    hboxlayout.addWidget(identity_view)
    #
    widget.setLayout(hboxlayout)
    
    pushbutton.clicked.connect(main_view.insertItem)
    
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Well, for starters, [`setData()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData) expects a `bool` as return type (`True` if the value has been set, `False` otherwise), but you're returning a boolean value **only** when `EditRole`/`FontRole` are requested *and* the row is valid, which means that for any other cases (any other [`ItemDataRole`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)) you're returning `None` (which clearly is not a `bool` type). Other than that we cannot really help you without a proper [mre] (the model is empty!), so adding a valid and complete answer is impossible.

Comment: Also, please try to use and provide more *readable* code. Functions should always be separated by a blank line. Having and class definitions so close together is really annoying to read (not only to us, but to you too!). Read more about this and other **important** styling topics on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insertRows()` function should not use `beginResetModel()` (which, as the name suggests, begins a model **reset**), nor `layoutChanged()`: not only it should always be called following a `layoutAboutToBeChanged()`, but that feature should only be used when the model is being *sorted*.

Emitting `dataChanged()` is also pointless, as it's implied that an inserted row will cause the view to call `data()` on the new indexes.

```
    def insertRows(self, position, rows=1, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, position, position+rows-1)
        for i in range(rows):
            self.items.insert(position+i, ListItem())
        self.endInsertRows()
        return True
```

Also note that you defined `index()` twice, but only the second one is used and actually correct, due to the `if row > len(self.items) - 1:` check opposed to `>=` of the previous, which is wrong. In any case, if you're using QAbstractListItem, which is a mono dimensional model, there's absolutely no need to override `index()` and you can use the default implementation.

Comment: Very great! Especially to delete the overriding of index() was the crucial point for avoiding bug.

Comment: That is to say, dataChanged takes an effect on the just existing item, but to me, I used it to the new one. So dataChanged is used in setData. I should have read a comment of Qt code, not reference. [https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.cpp.html] Thanks.

Comment: @Haru you used `dataChanged` with the parent, in this specific case the parent is always the root index (which is invalid for 1D and 2D models) so the result is an update on the whole view, but it's still pointless since the view would have been updated anyway for two reasons: 1. the mapper index has changed, which forces updating from the widgets (therefore calling `setData()` which emits `dataChanged`); 2. a new row has been (theoretically) added, which forces updates anyway. `dataChanged` must be emitted in `setData()`, or, to be more specific, whenever the result of `data()` might change.

Comment: Yes, >you used dataChanged with the parent, this is about `insertRows`. All the models in listmodel are changed because list model is 1D. I have reviewed my code of `QTableView`, and `QTreeView`, I don't know why it is, I didn't use  beginResetModel & dataChanged with the parent...@@; Anyway, I had no sufficient understanding of modeling system. Thanks.My knowledge was patchy.